# Is there a phrasal verb with the meaning of 'substitute'?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I know there's the phrasal **fill in / fill in for**, which means substitute or replace **someone** for what I know.

Though, what I am looking for is a phrasal to use in a phrase where **something** is being substited.

Ex: And with that, body language was *substituted/replaced* by...

Comment: What's wrong with your *replaced by*?

Comment: Maybe *change over* meaning replacing and exchanging.

Comment: There's nothing wrong to be honest with. Though I was specifing looking for a phrasal, due to an assigment. I was already expecting it to not exist, but a it wouldn't hurt to give a try.

Comment: *take the place of*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [changed over for](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/change-over?topic=replacing-and-exchanging) or change over to

> to stop using or having one thing and to start using or having something else:
>
> - We've just changed over from gas central heating to electric.

One real-world use includes

> I seem to recall that Honda, particularly, has been very good about doing model changeovers all in the same day, whereas the domestics, sometimes, it takes them months to change over for new models. ([Forbes.com](https://www.forbes.com/2009/05/27/automobile-industry-manufacturing-business-felax.html#608f4f6f40a2))

Definition for [change over to](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/change%20over%20to)

> to go (from one system, method, etc.) to (another)
>   - It will take a week to change over from the old computer network to the new one.
>
> - It operates on the 2.4-gigahertz frequency, but it can change over to Bluetooth, which is useful in homes with many dueling wireless devices. ([NY Times - Tech](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/11/22/technology/personaltech/22mouse.html))

I prefer [switch out for](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/switch-out-sth?q=switch%2Bout) which is mainly used in AmE and means

> to exchange something for something else:
>
> - The gallery switches out artwork every three months.
> - NASA had to order new parts and switch out the components on all three shuttles.

Some real-world examples include

> - Over an evening, the Chatham IPA may be switched out for Stranger Pale Ale, a Kelso swapped with a Keegan. ([NY Times-Food](http://travel.nytimes.com/2011/09/07/dining/reviews/earls-beer-and-cheese-nyc-restaurant-reviews.html))

and

> - Only the footwear changed, her chic version of Wellies switched out for brown suede boots as the ground dried. ([NY Times-magazine](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/09/07/magazine/07serial-t.html))

Alternatively, swap out for, which originates from the verb [swap](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/swap)

> an exchange, or something that is going to be or has been exchanged:
>
> - I thought Sam's lunch looked better than mine, so we did a swap.
> - uk This comic is a swap (= something that was exchanged) that I got from Nick.

Some examples of current use are

> - Its Ford V-8-60 engine was swapped out for that of a Jaguar XK-120. ([NY Times](http://wheels.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/10/31/piece-by-piece-the-hartung-collection-is-dismantled/))

and

> - Their favorite lamp has been swapped out for an obscure designer lighting system. ([NY Times](http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/09/20/tips-for-making-the-change-to-ios-7/))

Note that the preposition *"by"* in your example would need to be changed over to *"to"* or switched over for *"for"* or swapped out for *"for"* depending on the one you choose.